# R plotly fix one coordinate of nodes and leave one flexible

Tags: r, plotly

let's say that I would plot a Sankey diagram using plotly:

[image]

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

input <- tibble(label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
                color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
                source = c(0,1,0,2,3,0),
                target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
                
                x = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,1,0.9),
                y = c(0.3,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.3,0.7),
                
                value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2))

(fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",
  
  node = list(
    label = input$label,
    color = input$color,
    pad = 150, # distance between nodes
    x = input$x, 
    y = input$y
  ),
  
  link = list(
    source = input$source, 
    target = input$target, 
    value = input$value
  )
))
```

In this example, I have fixed both the `x` and the `y` coordinate. But let's say that I really only care about one of the two (in this instance `x`) and would like plotly to choose the second coordinate.

So in effect I would like to do something like this:

```r
input <- tibble(label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
                color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
                source = c(0,1,0,2,3,0),
                target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
                
                x = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,1,0.9),
                y = NA,
                
                value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2))
```

Then **plotly ignores both the x and the y coordinate** - indeed, I get the same results as if I just delete the x and y arguments in the node list (note e.g. the position of B2).

[image]

So it is equivalent to this:

```r
(fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",
  
  node = list(
    label = input$label,
    color = input$color,
    pad = 150 # distance between nodes
  ),
  
  link = list(
    source = input$source, 
    target = input$target, 
    value = input$value
  )
))
```

[image]

**Any ideas on how I can fix just one of the coordinates?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `plotly_build` to modify the y-coordinates after you created the plot. This gives you the opportunity to give the node a specific coordinate like this:

```r
library(tibble)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

input <- tibble(label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
                color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
                source = c(0,1,0,2,3,0),
                target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
                
                x = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,1,0.9),
                y = NA,
                
                value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2))

(fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",
  
  node = list(
    label = input$label,
    color = input$color,
    pad = 150, # distance between nodes
    x = input$x, 
    y = input$y
  ),
  
  link = list(
    source = input$source, 
    target = input$target, 
    value = input$value
  )
))
```

[image]

```r
your_fig <- plotly_build(fig)
your_fig$x$data[[1]]$node$y = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
your_fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see node B2 has now a different position. And others are still the same without manually changing.

Comment: Thank you Quinten - that's a really helpful start! But I'm afraid not quite what I was looking for - now B2 is still defined by a set x and y coordinate. I want all nodes to have a set coordinate for e.g. x and then for all coordinates to use the y value that is chosen by plotly

Comment: Is there a way to read out the x and y coordinates that plotly sends back?